# Why doesn't `index` qualify as a unique key, when passed as part of props to a custom react component?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, list, key, unique

When I just list the items directly, using `index` works. As in the following.

```
        <ol className="item-list">
            {
                props.items.map((item, index) => (
                    <li key={index}>{item}</li>
                ))
            }
        </ol>
```

But when I create a custom component to represent the list item, using `index` doesn't seem to qualify as being unique... And I end up getting a warning, as in the following.

```
        <ol className="item-list">
            {
                props.items.map((item, index) => (
                    <ShoppingItem
                        index={index}
                        item={item}
                    />
                ))
            }
        </ol>
```

The `ShoppingItem` is a simple component, like the following.

```
        const ShoppingItem = props => (
            <li key={props.index}>{props.item}</li>
        );
```

And the warning I get in the console is the following.

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read carefully the react docs for [Lists and Keys: Extracting components with keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys). The key goes on the component being mapped, not what it renders.

Incorrect

```
const ShoppingItem = props => (
  <li key={props.index}>{props.item}</li>
);

<ol className="item-list">
  {
    props.items.map((item, index) => (
      <ShoppingItem
        index={index}
        item={item}
      />
    ))
  }
</ol>
```

Correct

```
<ol className="item-list">
  {
    props.items.map((item, index) => (
      <ShoppingItem
        key={index} // <-- key goes here
        item={item}
      />
    ))
  }
</ol>
```